# Dynamic form creation and adding input fields

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, forms

I am currently working on a project that is an online quiz creation system which should have the functionality for the users to create their own quizzes, questions and possible answers and then send them to other users so they can solve the quiz. I am using c#  as back end. The issue that I am facing is creating the questions and possible answers in a quiz dynamically. I don't know how to create a dynamic form so the user can create a question and add possible answers. I want the user to be able to create a question like this:

> Question 1: Who is the first president of USA?
>
> a) John Adams
>
> b)Thomas Jefferson
>
> c) George Washington
>
> ***Add Answer***
>
> ***Create Another Question***

And if the user decides to add one more possible answer he presses "Add Answer". 
And when he presses "Create Another Question" it should create an empty form to type his question and add possible answers.

> Question 1: Who is the first president of USA?
>
> a) John Adams
>
> b) Thomas Jefferson
>
> c) George Washington
>
> **d) Some President**
>
> ***Add Answer***
>
> ***Create Another Question***

Has anyone done something similar? I have been searching for a while and I couldn't find what I need.
I am not looking for a complete code solution just some help so I can continue my project.

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you could specify whether you are using any js Framework like [Angular](https://angular.io/) or not that would make it easier to provide a sample but since its not the case, i made a same function in vanilla js which will be helpful with Adding dynamic fields functionality.

```
function addAnswerFields(){

   //Get reference of container and append Text in it
   var container = document.getElementById("container");
   container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Answer "));

   //Get reference of container and append Input field in it
   var input = document.createElement("input");
   input.type = "text";
   container.appendChild(input);

   // Add Br tag to move input fields on next line
   container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
```

When the User clicks on **Create Another Question**, a field will pop up for him to type the answer. Further more, a suggestion would be that you can add a button on the right side of the field. Upon clicking the button, field will be replaced with the P tag or any other tag you are using to show it as an Answer. Hope this helps!